# Stream which implements a Seek method

Tags: stream, go

I'm trying to find an interface which allows me to create a stream which allows seeking (just a Reader is fine, too) from either a file or `[]byte`, but can't seem to find anything in the godoc. Some of the types in the `bufio` package would work quite well, but they don't appear to support seeking.

Is there something I overlooked which would fit what I'm looking for?

Comment: Call whatever you like, but a stream with seek capability is not a stream but a buffer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both `*os.File` (for files) and `*bytes.Reader` (for having an `io.Reader` from a `[]byte`) implement the `io.Seeker` interface and thus have a `Seek` method.

```
io.Seeker is implemented by...
        *bytes.Reader
        *io.SectionReader
        io.ReadSeeker
        io.WriteSeeker
        io.ReadWriteSeeker
        mime/multipart.File
        net/http.File
        *os.File
        *strings.Reader
```

So if you're working with a file, thus very likely `*os.File`, you don't need to do anything additional to be able to seek it. Just make sure that if you're using interfaces instead of concrete types that you do not want an `io.Reader` but an `io.ReadSeeker`.

Comment: Wow, thank you! I missed the `bytes` package too I guess. Just curious, how did you manage to see what the `io.Seeker` interface is implemented by?

Comment: <shameless plug>I wrote a tool called "implements" (https://github.com/dominikh/implements) that can display "T implements I" and "I is implemented by T" relationships. In this case I ran `implements -interfaces io -types std -reverse` and scrolled to io.Seeker.